# Firebase unity mobile game set firestore data to offline while player offline

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

As title, I am using unity for building a mobile game and going to mark a player as offline, so other players will know that(show offline icon beside the player's name). I've tried when the Application is not focusing, update firestore doc's field to offline, but in some situations, it not working( ex. application crash, out of battery, or others).
Is any way to make sure when a player left the game, mark this player is offline correctly.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you can detect a players connection status via Firestore? If that's the question, the answer is no, Firestore does not offer any kind of presence system. However, the Realtime Database does see [Managing Presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

Comment: Not specific Firestore.  Do other services on Firebase meet my requirements? I don't use Realtime Database for now.

Comment: I set Firestore field to let other players know if this player is online or not, the problem is I can't change the field to offline correctly. I have no way to change the field to offline while the player quit the game.

Comment: The Realtime Database would work well for this as if a user disconnects from the server, a piece of data is written by the server to a node (you defined) on the server, which could then, for example, notify the other players that player is offline. All players would be observing this node for changes so it would be simple to detect when a player goes offline or comes online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update a specific path in the Database with the current timestamp. So, on other player side, you have to do a little calculation to find out if last timestamp already exceeded a threshold (1 minute) from the current timestamp.

Comment: If a player is disconnected (per the question) then their client won't be able to add/update any data on the server so this answer would not work

Comment: No, it will work because you are going to compare current time with last server time. If it's greater than inactive threshold, you can determine player is inactive. Also, that's how other messaging app determine active/offline status if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @SrejonKhan Do you mean while a player is online send update timestamp to firestore per minute, so other players know the player's last updated timestamp? If over 1 minute, it means offline?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try it. So far, it seems the only effective way to do that.

Comment: @Scozirge2 This is going to cost a fortune! This solution would mean that every player write data to Firebase every minute AND every player read Firebase data every minute. A couple hundred players would mean thousands of read and writes. To be specific; 100 players playing during a 24 hour period would equate to 144,000 reads/writes per day. And that's only 100 players... Ouch.

Comment: @Jay yes, as you said, it costs much, but I just use this logic to make cloud function execute every minute or hour, to get all "online player's docs" and check if they are still online. if not make it offline.

Comment: @Jay 
For the client-side(unity), While the Player unfocuses unity will be marked offline state, and  I will make the player listen to friend's docs, so if his friend changes the online state, he will know that.

Comment: @Jay This is my plan, I haven't done it yet, I am still working on other things now, but when I succeed, I will reply here again. Hope it works.

Comment: @Jay If everything is going right, when a player's unity unexpectedly crashes so he still keeps online(but he is actually offline), the cloud function will get this player and mark it offline.

Comment: @Scozirge2 Sounds like an interesting approach. OR and another option you could leverage the Realtime Database Online Persistence which would not involve any cloud functions or really any significant costs.